# Strange behavior when concatenating a sequence to a map (Scala 2.13)

Tags: scala, generics, types, collections, system

I have this simple program below. I was expecting all results to indicate that a map concatenated with a sequence would give a map. It is strange that the case 3 brings an iterable instead of a map. I guess that this is due to the fact that there are two distinct operators "++" on a map, as shown below. So the question is what is the difference between "Map[_, _]" and "Map[Any, Any]". Thanks for your insights.

[image]

```
    def test1[A, B](map: Map[A, B], a: A, B: B) = {
      val map2 = map ++ Seq(a -> b)
      println("Test 1 " + map.getClass + " / " + map2.getClass)
    }

    def test2(map: Map[Any, Any], a: Any, B: Any) = {
      val map2 = map ++ Seq(a -> b)
      println("Test 2 " + map.getClass + " / " + map2.getClass)
    }

    def test3(map: Map[_, _], a: Any, B: Any) = {
      val map2 = map ++ Seq(a -> b)
      println("Test 3 " + map.getClass + " / " + map2.getClass)
    }

    // Test 1 class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1 / class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2
    test1(Map(1 -> "A"), 2, "B")

    // Test 2 class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1 / class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2
    test2(Map(1 -> "A"), 2, "B")

    // Test 3 class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1 / class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
    test3(Map(1 -> "A"), 2, "B")
```

Answer (score 0):

In first 2 cases you have a situation when you have a `Map[K, V]` and `Seq[(K, V)]` - because `Seq[A] <: Iterable[A]`, Scala would pick more specific case with `++(seq: Iterable[(K, V)]): Map[K V]`.

In the third case, however, you are using existential type. It means that "there is some type X and Y for which your type is `Map[X, Y]`" whereas sequence you are adding is `Seq[(A, B)]` - `A` and `B` might be of type `X` and `Y` but since we don't know anything about them we cannot assume that. You can pass empty map of type `Map[Nothing, Nothing]` or `Map[Unit, Unit] = Map(() -> ())` and it would gladly accept it.

What can it do in this case? Well, all `Map`s are sequences of pairs (that happens to ensure that the first element of the pair is unique) and it provides `++` that does just that - concatenate your `Iterable[Z]` to that sequence.

So, it all boils down to the fact that `_` in type signature means existential type. `Map[_, _]` is a shortcut for `Map[X, Y] forSome { type X; type Y }`. You know that there is some type that would fulfill the requirements, but neither you nor the compiler knows enough to prove anything about it. And since Scala (and most typed languages) picks up the most specific definition (what "more specific" means is defined in the languages specification) `Map[X, Y] ++ Seq[(X, Y)]` picks the version that returns `Map[X, Y]` and when it cannot prove that types align, it returns `Iterable`.

If you run this in ammonite to check your output types you'll see that the typ of the third case is `Iterable[(Any, Any)]` as Scala had to find a common type for `(_, _)` and `(K, V)`. REPLs shows interred types better than runtime reflection that looses information due to type-erasure.

```
@     def test1[A, B](map: Map[A, B], a: A, b: B) = {
        map ++ Seq(a -> b)
      }
defined function test1

@

@     def test2(map: Map[Any, Any], a: Any, b: Any) = {
        map ++ Seq(a -> b)
      }
defined function test2

@

@     def test3(map: Map[_, _], a: Any, b: Any) = {
        map ++ Seq(a -> b)
      }
defined function test3

@

@     test1(Map(1 -> "A"), 2, "B")
res15: Map[Int, String] = Map(1 -> "A", 2 -> "B")

@

@     test2(Map(1 -> "A"), 2, "B")
res16: Map[Any, Any] = Map(1 -> "A", 2 -> "B")

@

@     test3(Map(1 -> "A"), 2, "B")
res17: collection.immutable.Iterable[(Any, Any)] = List((1, "A"), (2, "B"))
```